# Are triangles rendered in order in a single draw call/command in Vulkan?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

Related to this question about [ordering or triangles in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411730/triangle-drawing-order-in-directx-opengl) , I'm wondering what the situation is in Vulkan. To illustrate:

1. Example. A GUI batches a whole bunch of vertices for many windows/widgets and embeds the zvalue/depth in each vertex. In many cases you use one draw call to render a lot. For this to work then the order of each triangle/vertex in the primitive being rendered must be preserved. I've seen IMGUI do this.

If the ordering is preserved, then is it also for blending? Or just the depth buffer writing/reading? For example, consider the following example:

2. I have 100 meshes, and they are all solid (no transparency). I push the vertices all into a buffer, and submit ONE draw call to draw TRIANGLES. If the depth buffer is written for triangle 1 before triangle 2, then the correct ordering will happen.
3. My 100 meshes have transparency. None of them overlap in space. And I order them by depth. Will triangle 1 be blended onto triangle 2 correctly (triangle 1 comes before triangle 2)?

If it works for the depth but not the blending then is it a case that the depth buffer reads/writes are ordered corresponding with the triangle input order but not the color buffer reads/writes? If so, why is this?

Edit: The question marked as duplicate asks about rendering order "between draw calls". This question is about order WITHIN a draw call, and I've learned is referred to as "rasterisation order".

Answer (score 2):

0. Vulkan rasterises triangles as if in order, unless you specify that it is fine otherwise with an [AMD out-of-order rasterisation extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_AMD_rasterization_order.html). However, the gpu will process the triangles and vertices in parallel, but it only affects you in certain circumstances. The reason graphics APIs preserve triangle order is mostly for possability of transparency sorting: for blending.
1. If gui embeds depth information, then the order doesn't matter, unless some elements have same depth and draw on top of each other. The depth buffer makes it so no matter the order of triangles, only the closest(topmost, whatever) pixels are rasterised; For every pixel that appears, if depth tests are enabled, it compares(comparison operator can be chosen) the value that is already stored with the new pixel, and only if comparison returns true will it write the pixel and depth(if depth writes are enabled).
2. Depth generally doesn't care about triangle ordering, but they are ordered correctly anyway.
3. Transparency cares about triangle ordering, and so will only work if you sort triangles beforehand(unless you have commutative blend operator and disabled depth testing). Depth testing makes sure your transparent objects don't appear in front of your opaque geometry.